# Trying to install Click Modular Router and need /usr/src/linux to install as kernel module

Tags: installation, kernel, dependencies, router

I'm trying to install [Click Modular Router](https://github.com/kohler/click/blob/master/INSTALL) as a Linux Kernel Module.

I ran the command

```
sudo ./configure --enable-linuxmodule
```

And I got the following error

```
Can't find /usr/src/linux, so I can't compile the linuxmodule driver! (You may need the --with-linux=DIR option.)
```

I then ran the following command

```
sudo ./configure --enable-linuxmodule --with-linux=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-55-generic-pae
```

And I got the following error

```
Can't find Linux System.map file in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-55-generic-pae. (You may need the --with-linux=DIR and/or --with-linux-map=MAP options.)
```

I need to set this up in such a way that I can put this in an automated deployment script. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$: LINUX_VERSION=`uname -r` ./configure --with-linux=/usr/src/linux-headers-$LINUX_VERSION --with-linux-map=/boot/System.map-$LINUX_VERSION
```

If other parts are required, you may need to pass options for them in the same way, if they are for versioned pieces.

The best solution for automated deployment, would be to package it as a debian package, that is installed with `dkms` so that the kernel module will automatically get rebuilt when new kernels are installed in the system. You can see the `virtualbox-dkms` package, and other similar `-dkms` named packages, for how to do this.